# Eclipse can not push to Github

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have installed EGit and create a repo and push it to github using the following steps:

Step1:
[image]

Step2:
[image]

Step3:
[image]

Step4:
[image]

Step5:
[image]

Step6:
[image]

I get the following error:

Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/mleoking/JavaGnuplotHybrid.git (https://github.com/mleoking/JavaGnuplotHybrid.git: error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: index-pack abnormal exit)

I have also tried to use ssh but it even does not allow me to pass step3. With http I can pass step3.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I generally use the [command line](http://git-scm.com) for my git work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problems by myself:

I simply deleted the git repository for my project and then create a fresh new git repository following this guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Getting_Started

And then still use the same steps, using https rather than ssl. I successfully committed it to github: https://github.com/mleoking/JavaGnuplotHybrid

I do not really know where was the problem. But eventually the above steps work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the ssh address of your repository. http is read-only.

```
git@github.com:mleoking/JavaGnuplotHybrid.git
```

Answer (score 0):

On custom linux repos it could be a permissions error:

```
cd <path_to_git_folder.git>
chmod -R 777 *
```